# How to get Spock to match in Reactor similar to Mockito?

Tags: groovy, junit, mockito, project-reactor, spock

I am trying to test a class that will call another web service to fetch data if a `null` value is provided.  My JUnit + Mockito test works great, but I cannot get my Spock test to match in the `then:` block.  The error returned during the Spock test is:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method map() on null object
```

Which is because my mocked method is not matching, and therefore returns `null`.

**Spock test (not working)**

```
class MySpec extends Specfication {

    def mockCollaboratingService = Mock(CollaboratingService)
    def service = new MyService(collaboratingService: mockCollaboratingService)

    def "should call another service if the provided start value equals null"() {
        given:
        def id = 123
        def startDate = null

        when: "the service is called"
        def result = service.getTransactions(id, startDate)

        then:
        1 * mockCollaboratingService.getData(id) >> Mono.just(new SomeMockResponse(key: "123"))

        StepVerifier
            .create(result)
            .consumeNextWith({
                // assertions here
            })
            .verifyComplete()
    }
}
```

**JUnit + Mockito (working)**

```
class AnotherSpec {
    def mockCollaboratingService = Mockito.mock(MockCollaboratingService)
    def service = new MyService(collaboratingService: mockCollaboratingService)

    @Test
    @DisplayName("should call the statement service if the given start date is null")
    void shouldCallStatementServiceIfStartDateEqualsNull() {
        def id = 123
        def startDate = null

        // and some fake data returned from the api
        Mockito.when(mockCollaboratingService.getData(id)).thenReturn(Mono.just(new SomeMockResponse(key: "123")))

        //when
        def result = service.getTransactions(id, null)

        //then
        StepVerifier
                .create(result)
                .consumeNextWith({
                    Mockito.verify(mockStatementService, Mockito.times(1)).getLastStatement(enterpriseToken)
                    assert it.transactionId == 123
                })
                .verifyComplete()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock handles mocking differently than mockito, have a look at [combining mocking and stubbing](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0-M4/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing). Furthermore, all interactions must be finished before the `then` block, as Spock verifies them as first thing. With reactor, it is actually `StepVerifier` that is executing the code. The line `def result = service.getTransactions(id, startDate)` only creates a cold Mono/Flux, but doesn't to anything.

So, you have to reorder your tests slightly.

```
class MySpec extends Specfication {

    def mockCollaboratingService = Mock(CollaboratingService)
    def service = new MyService(collaboratingService: mockCollaboratingService)

    def "should call another service if the provided start value equals null"() {
        given:
        def id = 123
        def startDate = null

        when: "the service is called"
        def result = service.getTransactions(id, startDate)

        and: "code is executed"
        StepVerifier
            .create(result)
            .consumeNextWith({
                // no explicit mock assertions necessary
                assert it.transactionId == 123
            })
            .verifyComplete()

        then:
        1 * mockCollaboratingService.getData(id) >> Mono.just(new SomeMockResponse(key: "123"))

    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick -- do you know if I were to call a `map` on the returned `Mono`, how can I get Spock to match on the call within `map`?  I am getting a `Too few invocations for 1 * mockMapper.mapTransaction(_) >> Mono.just(new Transaction())`

Comment: I think it has something to do with it being a cold `Mono`... but I'm not sure

Comment: Without seeing the code it is hard to tell, but the basic principle remains, you need to list all interactions in the `then` block and execute your code in the `when` block.

Comment: System under test looks like this:
`service.getData(id).map({ anotherService.mapTransaction(it) })
`

And my `then` block looks like this:
`1 * mockService.getData(id) >> Mono.just(new SomeMockResponse())`

`1 * mockAnotherService.mapTransaction(_) >> Mono.just(new Transaction())`

Comment: I will post another question if that is more appropriate!

Comment: It might be best if you could provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve