# StepVerifier::expectError accepts any exception in Spock

Tags: groovy, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spock, reactive

I'm testing a class that uses Spring Boot's webflux library, and I've encountered strange behavior with `StepVerifier::expectError`. Specifically, I can pass *any* type (even String!) to the method and the test passes. My method under test should respond with an error Mono for this particular test, and the mono should contain a custom exception. My understanding from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565614/how-to-get-spock-to-match-in-reactor-similar-to-mockito) is that I have the `StepVerifier` operating in the correct block. What is going wrong here?

Class under test:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PaymentsBO {
    private final ContractClient contractClient;

    public Mono<Void> updatePaymentInfo(Request record) {
        return contractClient
                .getContract(UUID.fromString(record.getContractUuid()))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.error(() -> new CustomException(
                        "Contract Service responded with a non-200 due to "
                                + throwable.getCause())))
                .flatMap(
                    // happy-path logic
                );
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
def "Returns an error if the Contract Service returns a non-200"() {
    given:
    def testSubject = new PaymentsBO(contractServiceMock)
    def contractServiceMock = Mock(ContractClient)
    
    when:
    def result = testSubject.updatePaymentInfo(record)

    and:
    StepVerifier.create(result)
        .expectError(String.class)

    then:
    1 * contractServiceMock.getContract(CONTRACT_UUID) >> Mono.error(new ContractServiceException())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `StepVerifier` docs we can read that verification must be triggered by calling one ot the `verify` methods

> Trigger the verification of the resulting StepVerifier on its Publisher using either verify() or verify(Duration). (note some of the terminal expectations above have a "verify" prefixed alternative that both declare the expectation and trigger the verification).
> https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html

Your code doesn't use a `verify` method.

Please consider these two cases:

```
    @Test
    void without_verify() {
        Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException(""))
                .as(StepVerifier::create)
                .expectError(NullPointerException.class);
    }
    @Test
    void with_verify() {
        Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException(""))
                .as(StepVerifier::create)
                .expectError(NullPointerException.class)
                .verify();
    }
```

`without_verify` is passing because no verification has been triggered.

`with_verify` is failing because verification has been triggered.

Comment: Yup, I eventually figured this out, but thanks for confirming. Someone else had suggested using `verifyComplete`, but that's not an option to chain from `expectError`, so I was a little stumped.